# lambda capture by value mutable doesn't work with const &?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Consider the following:

```
void test( const int &value )
{
    auto testConstRefMutableCopy = [value] () mutable {
        value = 2; // compile error: Cannot assign to a variable captured by copy in a non-mutable lambda
    };

    int valueCopy = value;
    auto testCopyMutableCopy = [valueCopy] () mutable {
        valueCopy = 2; // compiles OK
    };
}
```

Why is the first version a compile error when I've declared the lambda as mutable and captured `value` by value (which I thought made a copy of it)?

Tested with clang (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0), which is where the error message comes from, and Visual C++ (vc120).

Comment: GCC trunk, too ("error: assignment of read-only variable 'value'")

Comment: The `const`-ness of the source variable does seem to trump the `mutable`-ness of the lambda.  Changing it to `[value=value]` solves the error in gcc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> `[C++11: 5.1.2/14]:` **An entity is *captured by copy*** if it is implicitly captured and the *capture-default* is `=` or **if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an `&`**. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an object, or the referenced type otherwise.** *[..]*

The type of `value` inside your lambda is `const int`, because it was captured by copy from a `const int&`.

Thus, even though the lambda's call operator function is not `const` (you marked the lambda `mutable`), the actual implicit member `value` is of type `const int` and cannot be mutated.

Frankly, this seems absurd; I would expect this rule to say that the referenced type loses `const`ness, as it's a copy. The presence or absence of the `mutable` keyword on the lambda itself (and, thus, the presence or absence of the `const` keyword on the generated call operator function) should be the only access control here.

In C++14 you can work around this by capturing as `[value=value]`, which uses the same rules as `auto` and thus drops the `const`. C++'s great, ain't it?

Comment: Wouldn't that override the assumption/intent of the caller?

Comment: @underscore_d: The caller wrote `mutable`. To my mind, that intent is pretty clear, and this making the member itself `const` is way overkill.

Comment: Yeah, now that I've woken up and noted it being captured by value, I see what you mean. This looks like just another ambiguity introduced by the octopus having too many legs...

Comment: C++14's rules in this area look way more complicated. They may fix it via `[value=value]` which Drew suggested fixes the problem in GCC at least. I haven't delved into this.

Comment: Yes, init-capture loses the const, since it uses `auto`'s rules. I think the const-preserving-ness of simple by-value captures is by design.

Comment: Hm, I see, and the workaround is nice but I think that I agree with your first statement - they should look at amending the standard IMO as the intent is pretty clear in my example code. Personally, I'd prefer to label a lambda const over having to declare it mutable when I want to modify a capture-by-value.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the `[value=value]` workaround doesn't seem to be supported in VC++ yet, at least not vc120 (haven't checked vc140 but I'd be curious to know if it works there).

Answer (score 5):

`mutable` allows a lambda to modify copy of a non-const parameter captured by copy, but it does not allow it for `const` parameters.

So this code works (and outputs `inside 2 outside 1`):

```
int a = 1;
[a]() mutable {
    a = 2; // compiles OK
    cout << "inside " << a << "\n";
}();
cout << " outside " << a << "\n";
```

But if we omit `mutable`, or make a `const int`, the compiler gives an error.

In our case, the first lambda gives an error because `value` is `const`:

```
void test( const int &value )
```

If we make `copyValue` `const`:

```
const int valueCopy = value;
```

then the same error will occur with the second lambda.