# Capturing lambda in std::function results in extra copies

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I am trying to write some code which allows me to call a function at some later time by storing the function call and its arguments in a lambda/std::function.  Ideally, the arguments would only be copied ONCE (and moved oterhwise) but the smallest number of copies I can achieve seems to be 2.

```
//==============================================================================
// INCLUDES
//==============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

//==============================================================================
// VARIABLES
//==============================================================================

static std::unique_ptr<std::function<void()>> queueFunction;

//==============================================================================
// CLASSES
//==============================================================================

class Test {
public:
    Test(int a, int b = 20, int c = 30) : _a(a), _b(b), _c(c) {
        std::cout << "Test: Constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "Test: Destructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test(const Test& other) :
        _a(other._a)
    {
        std::cout << "Test: Copy Constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test(Test&& other) :
        _a(std::move(other._a))
    {
        std::cout << "Test: Move Constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test& operator=(const Test& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            _a = other._a;
        
            std::cout << "Test: Assignment Operator" << std::endl;
        }
        
        return *this;
    }
    
     Test& operator=(Test&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            _a = std::move(other._a);
        
            std::cout << "Test: Move Assignment Operator" << std::endl;
        }
        
        return *this;
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& v) {
        os << "{a=" << v._a << "}";
        return os;
    }
    
private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
    int _c;
};

//==============================================================================
// FUNCTIONS
//==============================================================================

void foo(const Test& t);
void _foo(const Test& t);

template <typename F>
void queue(F&& fn) {
    std::cout << "queue()" << std::endl;
    
    queueFunction = std::make_unique<std::function<void()>>(std::forward<F>(fn));
}

void dequeue() {
    std::cout << "dequeue()" << std::endl;
    
    if (queueFunction) {
        (*queueFunction)();
    }
    
    queueFunction.reset();
}

void foo(const Test& t) {
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl;
    
    queue([t](){
       _foo(t); 
    });
    
    //Only a single copy of Test is made here
    /*
    [t](){
       _foo(t); 
    }();
    */
}

void _foo(const Test& t) {
    std::cout << "_foo()" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t=" << t << std::endl;
}


//==============================================================================
// MAIN
//==============================================================================

int main() {
    std::cout << "main()" << std::endl;
    
    Test test1(20);
    
    foo(test1);
    dequeue();
    
    std::cout << "main() return" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
main()
Test: Constructor
foo()
Test: Copy Constructor
queue()
Test: Copy Constructor
Test: Copy Constructor
Test: Destructor
Test: Destructor
dequeue()
_foo()
t={a=20}
Test: Destructor
main() return
Test: Destructor
```

Which makes no sense to me.  Shouldn't the lambda capture the instance of Test once, then forward that lambda all the way to the new std::function thus causing a move?

If I modify my queue function as such I can at least get rid of once copy.

```
void queue(std::function<void()> fn) {
    std::cout << "queue()" << std::endl;
    
    queueFunction = std::make_unique<std::function<void()>>(std::move(fn));
}
```

Output:

```
main()
Test: Constructor
foo()
Test: Copy Constructor
Test: Copy Constructor
queue()
Test: Destructor
dequeue()
_foo()
t={a=20}
Test: Destructor
main() return
Test: Destructor
```

But I still cannot understand where the extra copy is coming from.

Can someone help to enlighten me?

Comment: Are you using [Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/std::function-makes-a-lot-of-moves-upon/1249768?port=1025&fsid=81ff9e1a-9ca2-4b9e-b129-5855c0be823c&entry=myfeedback&ref=native&refTime=1632774851302&refUserId=212cf051-8e85-459b-8a31-fa05d00d44a6)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, I am just using gcc (version 8.1.0)

Comment: Ok, odd. I wrote a trouble report (the link above) on VS because I found it copying 1 time + moving 4 times on a signle assignment to a `std::function`. For gcc and clang I found 1 copy + 1 move. What do you get with your gcc if you run the program in my link? I just noticed that the newest gcc manages with only a copy, no move.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I get the following output:
Foo()
Foo()
-- constructing func --
Foo(const Foo&)
Foo(Foo&&)
~Foo() 1
-- assigning to func --
Foo(const Foo&)
Foo(Foo&&)
~Foo() 2
~Foo() 3
-- end of program --
~Foo() 4
~Foo() 5
~Foo() 6

Foo destructor called 6 times

Comment: Ok, 1  copy + 1 move when doing a copy assignment. That's the same as I got. If you move assign instead you'll get 2 moves I guess. They seem to have improved this in latest gcc. Only one copy or one move is done now.

Comment: But as the answer to my report said, what they do may depend on the size of the actual object too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT the problem is the `const` of the `foo()` argument. When you capture `t` inside `foo(const Test& t)`, then the type of that capture inside the lambda is also `const`. Later when you forward the lambda, the lambda's move constructor will have no choice but copy, not move, the capture. You cannot move from `const`.
After changing foo to `foo(Test& t)` I get:

```
main()
Test: Constructor
foo()
Test: Copy Constructor
queue()
Test: Move Constructor
Test: Move Constructor
Test: Destructor
Test: Destructor
dequeue()
_foo()
t={a=20}
Test: Destructor
main() return
Test: Destructor
```

Alternative solution, mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485150/85696, is to use capture in the form `[t=t]`.

With move-capture and two other changes it is possible to eliminate this remaining copy constructor too:

```diff
- void foo(const Test& t) {
+ void foo(Test t) {
...
-    queue([t](){
+    queue([t =  std::move(t)](){
...
-    foo(test1);
+    foo(std::move(test1));
```

```
main()
Test: Constructor
Test: Move Constructor
foo()
Test: Move Constructor
queue()
Test: Move Constructor
Test: Move Constructor
Test: Destructor
Test: Destructor
Test: Destructor
dequeue()
_foo()
t={a=20}
Test: Destructor
main() return
Test: Destructor
```

Comment: Imagine that the lambda and queue aren't there and foo just calls _foo.  There should not be any copies of Test made because the const reference is passed along.  My goal is to still say that the arguments are const references, but a copy has to be made for the queue (i.e., the queue is an intermediary step but the functions would be called by themselves). Is that not possible?

Comment: I just did some research on lambdas. Could this be a case where declaring the lambda as "mutable" would help?

Comment: Mutable affects only `operator()` of the lambda, making it non-const. To make the member non-const you can use capture in the form `[t=t]`. I updated the answer.