# Why can I not mutate a const ref captured by value?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Take a look at this code snippet:

```cpp
int x = 3;
const int &y= x;
auto f = [y]() mutable{
  y = 0;
};
```

clangs gives error:

```sh
> clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:13:7: error: cannot assign to a variable captured by copy in a non-mutable
      lambda
    y = 0;
    ~ ^
1 error generated.
```

It works if capture by `[y=y]`.

Why is this behavior? Is it that compiler deduct type as const int? If so why clang gives error about non-mutable lambda?

[update]
Seems the first part of the question already has an answer as pointed out by others: [lambda capture by value mutable doesn't work with const &?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485041/lambda-capture-by-value-mutable-doesnt-work-with-const)
clang's error info seems to be a bug which is not discussed in that question. Should I delete the question?

Comment: It creates a copy with `[y=y]`: https://godbolt.org/z/M1rscxK5a

Comment: I think that error message is among the most confusing I've seen. I would expect the problem to be that `y` is const...

Comment: the code has an error, but the message is most certainly a bug in clang. The lambda is not "non-mutable". gcc is less confusing https://godbolt.org/z/hhKfMfnPj

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/40382